# comma delineation of consecutive endnotes

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

Consecutive footnotes can be separated by commas by invocation of the `multiple` option of the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to endnotes%
\footnote{First note.}%
\footnote{Second note.}.%
\end{document}
```

This comma delineation fails, however, if footnotes are converted to endnotes using the [`endnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to endnotes%
\footnote{First note.}%
\footnote{Second note.}.%
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

How can one preserve automated comma delineation of consecutive endnotes?

Comment: you need a revised version of footmisc; i'll see what i can do.  (the problem is that footmisc redefines \footnote and blunders on...)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

### Manual solution

An admittedly not very comfortable solution is doing it manually, for example with `KOMA-Script`'s `\multiplefootnoteseparator`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to
endnotes\footnote{First note.}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Second
  note.}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a standard class something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\multiplefootnoteseparator{%
  \textsuperscript{\multfootsep}\nobreak
}
\newcommand*\multfootsep{,}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to
endnotes\footnote{First note.}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Second
  note.}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package `scrextend` may also be loaded to integrate KOMA-Script's `\multiplefootnoteseparator` in standard classes.

### Automatic Solution

My package [`fnpct`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) offers a different solution. If loaded together with the `endnotes` “it just works”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}

Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to
endnotes\endnote{First note.}\endnote{Second note.}.  \theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

`fnpct` also reverses the fullstop and the footnote markers but that can be changed with a package option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{fnpct}
\setfnpct{reverse,before-punct-space=0pt}

\begin{document}

Comma delineation of consecutive footnotes fails upon conversion to
endnotes\footnote{First note.}\footnote{Second note.}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note. I tested the `fnpct` examples above due to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388809/, and I get an error about `\pdf@strcmp` being undefined, with up-to-date TL17.

Comment: Looked closer, it stems from the `translations` package (line 90). `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}`  will fix it, but I don't know if that's the best path.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks. That's a missing dependency in `translations`. I'll send a fix to CTAN later today

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the footmisc package did not work. I did the following

```
\footnote{note1}\vphantom{d}$^{\text{,}}$\footnote{note2}
```

It's quick and dirty but it worked.

Comment: Instead of `\vphantom{d}$^{\text{,}}$` I'd rather use `\textsuperscript{,} `