# Multiple endnotes at one point

Tags: footnotes, endnotes, comma-separated-list

I want to put my footnotes at the end, so I use endnoes (as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56146/89786). But I would also like to be able to put several endnotes at the same point, just like with the footnotes (see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28467/89786)

My Naive attempt is to try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}\footnote{And another one.}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

But this not not produces the 'comma' separation i desire.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the `fnpct` package mentioned in that post is now on CTAN and in  TeX Live/MikTeX, so you shouldn't have to download from Bitbucket.

Comment: Given, that no bitbucket donload is nececarry, would that warrant a reply to this post as well?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, clemens (or someone else) can just edit the answer in the other question.

Comment: Follow-up: If  `fnpct` didn't work (undefined control sequence error on `\pdf@strcmp`), add `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` before `\usepackage{fnpct}`.

Comment: The package did work. Thank you for linking to the other question.